# Crenulator - What is the exact meaning?

Tags: meaning

I understand that after cremation, the remains are put through a crenulator to reduce them to ashes and to sift out metals.  I assume it's a sort of shaker/sieve.

Comment: A shaker and sieve might be used after bone fragments have been powdered, to separate metals (dental, jewelry, prostheses, coffin nails) from bone dust, but the main mechanism in a cremulator often is a flail or [hammer mill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammermill) with metal flails or chains hinged to periphery of a disk or cylinder.  Ball mills and blender-like grinders also have been used.

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for is [cremulator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cremulator) *a device to grind the bone fragments that remain after cremation into fine powder.*

It's probably a slightly macabre jokey extension from [crenulate/crenate](http://www.yourdictionary.com/crenate) *(having a notched or scalloped edge, as certain leaves)* in reference to the fact that notched rollers are likely to be part of the grinder.

Comment: What piques my interest here is that *having a margin with small rounded teeth* seems to imply the the crenels are the teeth, but in castle terminology, crenels are the _spaces_ between the merlons (teeth).

Comment: @Jim: I'm not going to look up the etymology, but I think the fact that a leaf, for example, may be described as *crenulate* acknowledges the bits "nibbled out" of the potential straight edge, not the fact that there are "sticky-out" bits left to form the jagged edge.

Comment: @jwpat7: Thanks for info. Dunno what happened there - I changed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Crenulator.... a person who makes Crenulations. i.e. a specialist stone mason who specialises in building crenulations (merlons and crenules) on a medieval castle.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  This would benefit from a reference.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].